# attach event handler for dynamic element

Tags: javascript, magento

I try to attach event handler for dynamic element but failed.

Here's some of my code. I want event can be called by dynamic element. 
Maybe javascript provide function to support attach event for dynamic element automatically without bind it again such as jQuery live or on method.
I want to add functionality to load city data while state or province selected to Magento Sales > Order > Create New Order Page without have to search a correct javascript file and try to bind event on it again.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    function getCity(){
        id= this.selectedIndex;
        name= this.name;
        getKota(id, name);
    }

    billing_address_region_id= document.getElementsByName('order[billing_address][region_id]');
    shipping_address_region_id= document.getElementsByName('order[shipping_address][region_id]');

    var event = new Event('change');
    billing_address_region_id[0].addEventListener('change', getCity, false);
    shipping_address_region_id[0].addEventListener('change', getCity, false);
    billing_address_region_id[0].dispatchEvent(event);
    shipping_address_region_id[0].dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Thanks a ton

Comment: Can you share some html code too...

Comment: It just select box country, province, and city to load dynamic data. I just want event handler can be called by dynamic element.

Comment: Are you saying that the elements with class `order[billing_address][region_id]` and `order[shipping_address][region_id]` are loaded dynamically How and when? Or what do you mean by "dynamic element"?

Comment: I'm just add a little code to provide load dynamic city data to select box, element can be removed or added but event handler still can be called

Comment: OK, but that sounds like only the actual options are loaded dynamically, not the `<select>` element (I guess?) itself. In that case, your code should work fine. Please provide a **complete**, self-contained example which reproduces the issue. All we can do now is guess.

Comment: I'm adding functionality to load dynamic city data according to my country in Magento Sales > Order > Create New Order Page. there's prototype and scriptaculous. I try adding jquery library but there's error eventhough using jQuery.noConflict() so I'm try using javascript only. I don't insert script for AJAX Request because it looks like the problem just event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This solution is not tested.

What you could do since the target elements are added dynamically is to register a change event handler to the `window`, then see whether any of the target element fired the change event if so do your action.

```
window.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var el = e.target;
    if (el.name == 'order[billing_address][region_id]' || el.name == 'order[shipping_address][region_id]') {
        getKota(el.selectedIndex, el.name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work only for already existing elements. I recommend using jQuery.

Using jQuery, you can use "on" method.

```js
$('#elem').on('change', function(){
  // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: Please don't suggest to use a library if the author hasn't indicated that he wants to use one.

Comment: thanks but I'm using javascript only to prevent conflict with other javascript library